# Sub child element isnt changed

Tags: css

I have lorem ipsum text. as you can see below picture:

http://prntscr.com/viytf2

I want to change its font.

to make this, I wrote this code:

```
.icon-box > icon > details >  p {
    color:red;
}
```

but it doesnt change its color to red.morever, its property isnt shown on chrome inspect; so, its not about !important.

SO, how can I change its style?

https://resimli.yedek.deniz-tasarim.site/

Comment: yes, I have.this is my js selector : body > div.wrapper > div.elementor.elementor-395 > div > div > section.elementor-section.elementor-top-section.elementor-element.elementor-element-7a0b0d4a.elementor-section-full_width.elementor-section-height-default.elementor-section-height-default > div > div > div > div > div > div.elementor-element.elementor-element-14117cd.elementor-widget.elementor-widget-Our.Services2 > div > section > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.details > p

Comment: Hi there, please consider providing a [mcve] of the issue you're facing _within_ the question itself instead of providing a link to your site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using the class "icon" in your selector which, according to the markup on your website is a sibling of details and not a parent and therefore not part of the hierarchy. Also for "icon" and "details" you are missing the dots indicating that it is a class. This is probably the reason why the style is not applied.

Try this:

```
.icon-box > .details >  p {
    color:red;
}
```

To be less specific and avoid specificity war you might not even need all tags, classes and > inside the selector for the style to be applied.

Comment: body > div.wrapper > div.elementor.elementor-395 > div > div > section.elementor-section.elementor-top-section.elementor-element.elementor-element-7a0b0d4a.elementor-section-full_width.elementor-section-height-default.elementor-section-height-default > div > div > div > div > div > div.elementor-element.elementor-element-14117cd.elementor-widget.elementor-widget-Our.Services2 > div > section > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.details > p

Comment: I checked again. You need to take out ".icon" as it is a sibling of ".details" and not a child of it and therefore not part of the hierarchy. I updated my suggestion in the answer.